# Java Exercise in While Loop

Tags: java

I badly need help with this exercise.
I'm a newbie in Java and I hope someone could help me.
Here's the question:

Write a program called SumOfSeven to sum those
numbers from 1 to 100 that is divisible by 7. Display
the sum and the average. Use the “while-loop” to
answer this problem.

And here's my answer:

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int counter = 1;
        int sum = 0;

        while (counter<=100){
            while (counter % 7 ==0){
                sum+= counter;
            }

            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
    }
}
```

I tried executing my answer but the software kept on loading and did not display any answer. I was able to successfully execute the program using this another code I made:

```
public class SumOfSeven {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int sum = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        while (counter<=100){
            sum+= counter;
            counter+=7;
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);   
    }
}
```

I just wanted to know why the first one didn't work.

Best Regards,

Faye

Comment: `while (counter % 7 ==0)` is an infinite loop, you need an `if` condtion here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner while loop is infinite (when `counter % 7 == 0`, which is true in the 7th iteration of the outer while loop, when counter reaches 7) and pointless, since you only want to add `counter` to the `sum` one time when it is divisible by 7.

It should be replaced by an if statement :

```
while (counter<=100){
    if (counter % 7 ==0) {
        sum+= counter;
    }

    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Also, put `counter++` inside the `if` block. You need to count only the values divisible by 7

Comment: Didn't know that the inner loop is infinite. I thought the inner loop would execute only up to counter <=100. Thanks Again Eran!

Comment: @AhmadWabbi Doing that would make the outer while loop infinite. If the count of numbers divisible by 7 is required, it will have to be stored in a separate variable.

Comment: @Eran Ah sure. Didn't see that the outer loop was on `counter` too

Answer (score 1):

Change `while(counter % 7 == 0)` to `if(counter % 7 == 0)`